# Does Apple's EFI patch Thunderbolt devices to Windows 10?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dual-boot, efi

So, I've been rattling with myself about this for a bit. I've followed [5SH-2a's guide of EFI Bootcamp](http://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2fy3be/by_popular_demand_my_better_than_bootcamp_guide/) to no avail. I decided to try it on my own, by mapping an NTFS Partition on my hard drive to a VMDK, and using VMWare Fusion to install it, but that has not worked. I am on a Mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro (Identifier: MacbookPro9,2) running Yosemite v10.10. I am trying to install the Windows 10 Tech Preview. When I try and boot via EFI, with my CalDigit Thunderbolt Hub active, Windows goes into an infinite loop, and never boots, while simultaneously power-cycling the devices attached to my hub. When I deactivate the hub, EFI Boot works just fine. When I boot in eBIOS mode, regardless wether I have my hub active or not, Windows boots just fine, using my hub natively. Could this be an issue with Apple's implementation of EFI not connecting the hub to Windows? Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: This issue happens differently on Windows 8, where Windows boots, but doesn't recognize the Thunderbolt hub in EFI mode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Beta products.

Comment: The community is leaning towards accepting questions involving public beta products, see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/office-for-mac-2016-on-or-off-topic-until-release